# Why isn't the recursion code working properly? [closed!]

Tags: java, recursion

So i am trying to make a program that finds a word within a string, or basically a word within a word. My thought process is to check if each substring matches with the word and use recursion to cut down the string one character at a time. I've spent a lot of time on it but it's not working and I really don't understand why. Please help, I've been really frustrated at this for a while now.

```
public static boolean yodo(String sen, String word)
{
    String sentence = sen;
    String wordy = word;
    int wordLength = word.length();
    int senLength = sentence.length();

    boolean result = false;

    if ((sentence.substring(0, wordLength)).equals(wordy))
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else 
    {

    yodo(sentence.substring(1), wordy);
    }

    return result;


}
```

Comment: The result of `yodo(sentence.substring(1), wordy);` is ignored.

Comment: `return sentence.contains(word);`

Comment: Why assign parameters to variable unless you want to change them? --- What is `senLength` used for? --- `(sentence.substring(0, wordLength)).equals(wordy)` is the same as `sentence.startsWith(wordy)`, which is shorter and much clearer about what it does. --- And as others have said, you should use the return value of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, return false if either length is 0.

Second, you need to return the value of yodo, not simply call it.

> return yodo(sentence.substring(1), wordy);

Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you this helped so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not working properly is that you are ignoring the result of the recursive call:

```
yodo(sentence.substring(1), wordy);
```

You should either assign it to `result` before returning, or return right away, and drop the declaration of `result` altogether.

In addition you need a *base case* to return `false` when `wordy` is longer than `sentence`. Otherwise your code is bound to crash when `sentence` becomes an empty `String`.